# Change class of tr if checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a table that has rows like:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td><a href="#">School</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">DD1 1AB</a></td>
    <td>80.10</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td><span class="active">Active</span></td>
    <td><a href="#">John Doe</a><br/>00000 000000</td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is when a user has selected the checkbox is change the the class of the parent `<tr>` to say selected so the user knows which row they have selected. NOTE: They can toggle these on and off!

Comment: Please stop writing "jQuery:" at the start of all your question titles. We already have a tags system.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a Q&A site, not a programmers for hire meeting place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming some of the checkboxed may come pre-checked, I'd take this approach:

```
// First add class for pre-checked entries
$(".xyz input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected");
});

// Then toggle class whenever checkbox state changes
$(".xyz input[type=checkbox]").live("change", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cUxmG/

To reduce overheads of searching the DOM twice, that can be combined into:

```
$(".xyz input[type=checkbox]").live("change", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("selected");
}).filter(":checked").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected");
});
```

It does the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/cUxmG/2/

Comment: what if checkbox's status is changed with js from a different place? (with click on row listener for example)

Comment: You could try manually triggering the "change" even from the js that does the change, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/cUxmG/18/

Answer (score 6):

```
$('table').delegate(':checkbox','change',function(){
  var $elem = $(this),
  $tr = $elem.closest('tr');

  if($elem.is(':checked')){
    $tr.addClass('highlight');
  }else{
    $tr.removeClass('highlight');
  }
  return false;

})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked'))
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('your_class');
   else 
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('your_class');
});
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: $(this).checked wouldn't work. $(this).prop('checked') would, or this.checked would. $(this) is the jQuery wrapped DOM element object.

Comment: `.closest("tr")` would be more robust than `.parent().parent()`. It's also easier to read.

Comment: yup, but this is faster, closest search next element, than check its nodeName, and it looks parents and childnodes, and next elements, this is direct to parent()

Comment: Good point. Balance between performance and maintainability can be tricky, and there's always the issue of premature optimisation at the expense of maintainability.