# jQuery checkbox select all and change background color on select

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with checkboxes in the first column, and a "select all" checkbox in the header. When I check a checkbox, I need the row color to change.

```js
var $tbl = $('#tbl');
var $bodychk = $tbl.find('tbody input:checkbox');

$(function () {
    $bodychk.on('change', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('hilite');
    });

    $tbl.find('thead input:checkbox').change(function () {
        var c = this.checked;
        $bodychk.prop('checked', c);        
    });
});
```

1. If you select the individual boxes, the row changes color
2. If you click the "select all" box, it'll toggle the other checkboxes.

But I can't get both working together. **[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/hb6cx0tn/6/)**

These questions come close but don't fully answer what might be wrong...

[Change class of tr if checkbox is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120636/change-class-of-tr-if-checkbox-is-selected)

[Jquery "select all" checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879608/jquery-select-all-checkbox)

Comment: ahh, i didnt notice your fiddle in the comments, haha yea, that is exactly how i implemented, except you used a function to toggle, nicely done.  if you had other things you wanted your checkbox to do (other than adding a class or two), then id suggest using `.trigger()` but as the issue is only with adding/removing a class, your fiddle is much cleaner. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/hb6cx0tn/9/

```
var $tbl = $('#tbl');
var $bodychk = $tbl.find('tbody input:checkbox');

$(function () {
    $bodychk.on('change', function () {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('hilite');
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('hilite');
        }
    });

    $tbl.find('thead input:checkbox').change(function () {
        var c = this.checked;
        $bodychk.prop('checked', c);
        $bodychk.trigger('change'); 
    });
});
```

i chose not to use toggle because it doesnt ensure that the checkbox is checked in order for the item to be highlighted.

the line `$bodychk.trigger('change');` causes the `.change()` event to trigger so that you're just not adding a class to the element, you're actually triggering the checking of the element.

Comment: How can I use this on only the first checkbox in the row?  I don't want it to toggle on the 3 other check boxes I have later in that row.

Comment: @BoltBait perhaps you can link me to your question so i can get a better understanding of what you want to do

Comment: I figured it out.  I simply add the onchange function to the checkbox when rendering the table (instead of adding it later like your example).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the same line you had in the single checkbox:

```
$bodychk.prop('checked', c).closest("tr").toggleClass('hilite');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hb6cx0tn/7/)

You're still locating the `tbody > input:checkbox` so you can still back out to the parent `tr` and toggle the class

Comment: That works. Thanks!

I ended up replacing the toggleClass as that was causing issues [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hb6cx0tn/8/)

Comment: @spikej: i think theres a bug with this solution. try clicking "column", then "item 1", then "column" again

Comment: @indubitablee thanks. I noticed that too, and replaced toggleClass. Your answer with the trigger is what I was after but couldn't figure out.